# Setting up Windows Phone 8.1 project in Xamarin Forms solution with MvvmCross

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have been developing my Xamarin Forms application for a while and right now I wanted to add Windows Phone project to it. I have tried to set it up with guide on MvvmCross GitHub project, but it seems outdated.

At first I have added Windows Phone 8.1 blank app project to the solution and proceeded with guide. I have added NuGet packages, which I needed, there weren't any problems with that, but then, when I was modifying App.xaml.cs and MainPage.xaml.cs files, I couldn't use classes which were used in samples and tutorial. When I was comparing references in my project with those in sample MvvmCross project I have spot some differences.

[My references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7GRz.png)

Suspicious thing to me is this MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Windows81 reference. After looking at MvvmCross repository for Xamarin Forms I have seen, that there is MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.WindowsPhone namespace with view presenter. So I was thinking, that maybe here is the problem.

After hours of trying and mixing code with Xamarin.Forms guide and my UWP project, I have came up to the place, where application is somehow staring, methods, which should be executing are executing (when I followed MvvmCross guide only, my first view model hadn't been constructed), but application is crashing at very beggining with this stacktrace:

```
System.TypeLoadException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233054
Message=Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Foundation'.
Source=mscorlib
TypeName=Windows.Foundation
StackTrace:
at System.StubHelpers.WinRTTypeNameConverter.GetTypeFromWinRTTypeName(String typeName, Boolean& isPrimitive)
   at System.StubHelpers.SystemTypeMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(TypeNameNative* pNativeType, Type& managedType)
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType, Object parameter)
   at MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views.MvxWrappedFrame.Navigate(Type viewType, Object parameter)
   at MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Windows81.MvxFormsWindows81PagePresenter.CustomPlatformInitialization(NavigationPage mainPage)
   at MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core.MvxFormsPagePresenter.TryShowPage(MvxViewModelRequest request)
   at MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core.MvxFormsPagePresenter.Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
   at MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views.MvxWindowsViewDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<ShowViewModel>b__0()
   at MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views.MvxWindowsMainThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(Action action)
   at MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views.MvxWindowsViewDispatcher.ShowViewModel(MvxViewModelRequest request)
   at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModelImpl(Type viewModelType, IMvxBundle parameterBundle, IMvxBundle presentationBundle, MvxRequestedBy requestedBy)
   at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel[TViewModel](IMvxBundle parameterBundle, IMvxBundle presentationBundle, MvxRequestedBy requestedBy)
   at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxAppStart`1.Start(Object hint)
   at PatrolHelper.WinPhone81.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
```

Here is implementation of my App.xaml.cs file:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
#if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
#endif

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            // TODO: change this value to a cache size that is appropriate for your application
            rootFrame.CacheSize = 1;

            // Set the default language
            rootFrame.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];

            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                // TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // Removes the turnstile navigation for startup.
            if (rootFrame.ContentTransitions != null)
            {
                this.transitions = new TransitionCollection();
                foreach (var c in rootFrame.ContentTransitions)
                {
                    this.transitions.Add(c);
                }
            }

            rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
            rootFrame.Navigated += this.RootFrame_FirstNavigated;
        }

        Setup setup = new Setup(rootFrame);
        setup.Initialize();

        IMvxAppStart start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        start.Start();

        if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
        }

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<forms:WindowsPhonePage
x:Class="PatrolHelper.WinPhone81.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:PatrolHelper.WinPhone81"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:forms="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>

</Grid>
```

and MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : WindowsPhonePage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        start.Start();

        var presenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewPresenter>() as MvxFormsWindows81PagePresenter;

        LoadApplication(presenter.MvxFormsApp);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it Windows Phone Silverlight or Windows Phone WinRT based app you have?

Comment: It is WinRT app

Comment: your app is crashing when opening first page. Do you have any static resources defined? Is it possible you upload the sample project somewhere?

Comment: I have no icons or any files defined on the first page it is in fact simple view itch label and button. If there is a way to solve it, I would not like to upload my project, but if there is a need for doing it I can uplod it tomorrow. Btw, thanks for replying.

Comment: I'd like to help, in fact I had similar error when configuring mvvmcross project for iOS/Android/UWP. But it was not a Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Can you show the sample and guide for me？ I would like to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys. Today I have thought, that I will give it one more shot and if I won't be able to run it, then I will post my code. I was struggling for about an hour and I have finally managed to run my start page.

I have opened [this sample](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms/tree/master/Samples/Example002XAML/Example.W81) and basically replaced my content of MainPage.xaml.cs, App.xaml.cs and Setup.cs with their implementation. Then I have started the build and voila, my main page showed up.

My problem was that I haven't noticed, that [this MvvmCross tutorial](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tip-Calc-A-Windows-Phone-UI-Project) was targeting Windows Phone Silverlight. Anyway thanks for replying and good luck with your projects.

Comment: Great. Was exactly my first question as you can see :)